# PHP Image Uploader - IE "pjpeg" MIME type, not working

Tags: php, image, internet-explorer, upload, mime

I am having a hard time with my image upload script, getting the images to upload in Internet Explorer.  I have been searching Google for a solution and adding the "image/pjpeg" mime type seemed to work for everyone, but I have added it to my code and still cannot get it to work.

Here is what I have:

```
$acceptedExts = array ('jpg','jpeg');

if (  in_array($ext,$acceptedExts)
  &&  (  $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"
      || $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
  &&  ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] < 16000000)) {
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: do `var_dump($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"])` to see what file type is being provided by the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a `var_dump($_FILES['uploaded_file'])` to see exactly what IE's sending. It may be `image/jpg` or something completely different. However, it's bad form to use the user-provided `['type']` field for validation. It's trivial to forge that value. Better use a server-side method to figure out file type, such as [`get_image_size()`](http://php.net/get_image_size) or the [`FileInfo`](http://php.net/fileinfo) library, both of which return the true mime-type of the file.

Comment: Ah, I did the var_dump and it said it was an image/png for some reason... Weird!  Any idea why?  Well that helped solved my problem, so now I just allowed the image/png and it works fine!  Thanks so much!