# PHP upload file to database not working with gif, jpeg and other filetypes

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, blob

I have a problem with some PHP/MySQL not working. I can upload files like .docx and .sql perfectly but when i try with .gif, .jpg .zip and .rar, it doesn't work.

Here is the upload form code:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['uploadError']))
{
    echo '<div id="error">There was an error uploading the file. Please try again</div>';
}
elseif ((!isset($_SESSION['dbusername']))&&(!isset($_SESSION['dbpassword'])))
{
    header('Location: ?page=login&uploadAttempt=true&attemptedSite=upload');
}
else
{
    echo '
    <center>
    <form class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadaction.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30720" />
    <p class="uploadfile">
        <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
    </p>
    <p class="submit">
        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="start" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    </p>
    </form></center>';
}
?>
```

Here is the uploadaction.php code:

```
    <?php
require('lib.php');
localhost_con('filehunt');
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['uploadedfile']['size'] > 0)
{
    $fileName = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['type'];

    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    }
    /*$fh = fopen($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], 'r');
    $theData = fread($fh, filesize($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']));
    $theData = mysql_real_escape_string($theData);
    fclose($fh); */
    $date = date("y/m/d : H:i:s", time());

    $sql = "INSERT INTO files (rowID, file, mimetype, data, uploaded_by, uploaded_date, size, times_downloaded) 
    VALUES (NULL, '$fileName', '$fileType', '$content', '$user', '$date', $fileSize, 0);";

    if (mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
        header('Location: index.php?page=search&uploadSucces=true');
    } 
    else echo mysql_error();
}
else header('Location: index.php?page=upload&uploadError=true');

?>
```

It gets inserted in the database, but the mimetype and data column is empty.
Can anyone tell me why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance
Adam

Comment: Side note: `addslashes` is not sufficient escaping, you need to use `mysql_real_escape_string`, and you should `die()` after each `header()`... but +1 for having code that, overall, doesn't make my eyes bleed.

Comment: Take a look at this post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387765/php-image-uploader-ie-pjpeg-mime-type-not-working][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387765/php-image-uploader-ie-pjpeg-mime-type-not-working

Comment: Hi, thanks! Why would i wanna run die() after header(), when it redirects away from the script? Thank you, Adam

Comment: Are `$fileName` and `$fileSize` entered successfully?

Comment: Check the data type you entered in the database.

Comment: The problem is that if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['uploadedfile']['size'] > 0) is false. Probably because of the $_FILES['uploadedfile']['size'] > 0 part, witch is weird since the .gif i'm testing with is 443,673 bytes

Comment: Hi, what do you exactly mean? Can you explain? Thank you in advance

Comment: like varchar, blob text etc. Does it match what you are sending to it?

Comment: It works with the most filetypes, so the problem is not the database. The column datatype is longblob and attribute: binary. Could it be because the file is too small for longblob?

Comment: HI Josh, yes, $fileName is entered correctly, but note the if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['uploadedfile']['size'] > 0) line. I think its the $_FILES['uploadedfiles']['size'] that is equal to 0, but i have no idea why. The problem mostly occurs with .gif files, but has also happened with .jpg, .zip and .rar

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with other type of files. The workaround is encoding the file with base64 that is safer to transmit (do not contain invalid characters that may truncate the streaming).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite shure, but this:

```
$fileType = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['type'];
```

must be like this:

```
$finfo = new finfo();
$fileType = $finfo->file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], FILEINFO_MIME);
```

Comment: Hi user1207792, i tried but i the code doesn't quite work. I wrote a little extra code to specify the error message, so i have the exact error message now. The MAX_FILE_SIZE is 30720 and the file im trying to upload is on 180 kb. The error message i get is "Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form" which is is wierd, since the file im uploading is under 30mb

Comment: You can try this options into your php.ini:
`upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M`
... or you can adjust as you wish.

Comment: Hmm... i changed upload_max_filesize to 31457280 bytes, and post_max_size to 31457280, and i still get the error, but i think the error is coming from the HTML from, even tho i set the max_file_size to 30mb

Comment: Do you have any restrictions/code specifications into your html form? Like `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="12345">`

Comment: I saw it 
`<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30720" />` ... just increase the value here to whatever you need.

Comment: Hi mlinuxgada, the value is set to 30mb which should me more than enough for a 180kb file...

Comment: Did you receive the posted file ... maybe there is some other limitation here?